# How can I open the user's profile contact using an Intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'd like to build an intent which opens the user's profile contact in the "Contacts" application. I've read that the profile/me contact is always at position 0 but it doesn't work with the snippet I've built:

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, "0"))
```

Could any of you tell me how I can resolve this?

Comment: Profile db is different from other contacts db. you should use different URI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source of the [`QuickSettings.java` Profile tile](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/QuickSettings.java#L305), I got this to work:

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI)
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use `ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI` instead.